# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to read the data from a database and pass the dates that have been selected from a datetime picker as values for the query. I keep getting all kind of error messages that are becouse of the wrong data type, i think.

What am i doing wrong here??

Please help.

P

```
            private void buttonRetrieveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openConnection();

        //TODO: Add function te retrieve data between dates enteren in datetimepickers
        DateTime datumVan = dateTimePickerVan.Value;

        DateTime datumTot = dateTimePickerTot.Value;

        string query = "select * from my_Table where date between '" + datumVan.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + datumTot.ToShortDateString() + "' order by date desc";

        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        adapter.Fill(dset, "my_Table");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dset;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "my_table";

        adapter.Update(dset, "my_Table");

        closeConnection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't treat dates as strings**. It's as simple as that, avoid converting them to strings in the first place, and you save yourself a whole heap of trouble.

So, instead of:

```
string query = "select * from my_Table where date between '" + datumVan.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + datumTot.ToShortDateString() + "' order by date desc";
```

Have instead:

```
string query = "select * from my_Table where date between @Van and @Tot order by date desc";
```

And then add parameters to the command object:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Van",datumVan);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tot",datumTot);
```

Let ADO.Net and SQL Server deal with the issue of translating .NET datetime values into SQL Server datetime values.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the SQL datetime type has a date range from : January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

And .NET datetime min value is 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

I would recommend you to check that you are not falling between ranges.

That means that if your datetime picker is not initiated with SQL min value it might return an invalid SQL date.

Comment: I would also recommend using parameters in your SQL statements and not directly inserting values to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem but my fix was simple:

Instead of

```
+ datumVan.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + datumTot.ToShortDateString() +
```

I changed to

```
+ datumTot.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + datumVan.ToShortDateString() +
```

Give it a try, if this helps.

Also, is your date is getting converted to string by use of ToShortDateString() but what format is that of your date in table ??

May be you can try following query as well:

select * from my_Table where CAST(date AS DATE) between CAST('" + ToShortDateString() + "' AS DATE) and CAST('" + datumTot.ToShortDateString() + "' AS DATE) order by date desc";